# Jaxb don't use bindings adapter after migrating from Java 1.8 to 11

Tags: java, jaxb, java-11

I'm trying to migrate an existing application from Java 1.8 to 11, in the application, we are generating sources from an xsd with this plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.jaxb.plugin.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <version>${jaxb.impl.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${jaxb.api.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                    <version>${jaxb.xjc.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                    <version>${jakarta-xml-api.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>horas</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
                        <quiet>true</quiet>
                        <packageName>client.model</packageName>
                        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                        <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/config/xsd</bindingDirectory>
                        <bindingFiles>bindings.xjb</bindingFiles>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
                        <schemaFiles>model.xsd</schemaFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And in the xsd we use the type

```
    <xs:simpleType name="dateTime" id="dateTime">
        <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <hfp:hasFacet name="pattern"/>
            <hfp:hasFacet name="enumeration"/>
            <hfp:hasFacet name="whiteSpace"/>
            <hfp:hasFacet name="maxInclusive"/>
            <hfp:hasFacet name="maxExclusive"/>
            <hfp:hasFacet name="minInclusive"/>
            <hfp:hasFacet name="minExclusive"/>
            <hfp:hasProperty name="ordered" value="partial"/>
            <hfp:hasProperty name="bounded" value="false"/>
            <hfp:hasProperty name="cardinality"
                    value="countably infinite"/>
            <hfp:hasProperty name="numeric" value="false"/>
          </xs:appinfo>
          <xs:documentation
            source="http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime"/>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:anySimpleType">
          <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"  fixed="true"
            id="dateTime.whiteSpace"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
```

In order to translate the date, we have this binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="model.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:globalBindings>
            <xjc:javaType name="org.joda.time.DateTime"
                          xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                          adapter="client.adapter.JodaDateTimeAdapter"/>
            <xjc:simple/>
        </jxb:globalBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

with a simple adapter

```
/**
 * Class adapter afin de traiter les objets de type {@link org.joda.time.DateTime}
 */
public final class JodaDateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, DateTime> {

    /**
     * Conversion d'une String représentant une date en objet {@link DateTime}
     *
     * @param value Une String représentant une date selon le pattern ISO8601
     * @return Un objet {@link DateTime}
     */
    @Override
    public DateTime unmarshal(String value) {
        return ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().parseDateTime(value);
    }

    /**
     * Conversion d'un objet {@link DateTime} en string selon le pattern
     *
     * @param value {@link DateTime} à convertir
     * @return Une String représentant une date selon le pattern ISO8601
     */
    @Override
    public String marshal(DateTime value) {
        return ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().print(value);
    }
}
```

It was working fine in 1.8 but after building with java 11, the binding seem to not work anymore, indeed, the class generated has XMLGregorianCalendar instead of joda.dateTime.

The bindings file is found because if I change the path in the POM, an error occur, so it mean that the binding is ok but for some reason, jaxb ignore it.

Do you know what should be changed in order to have joda.DateTime again please?

Comment: Some of `jaxb` code was removed from JDK 11. I see you already added them explicitly, buy you may need to double check the groupId and artifactId. Also, you can check in `mvn dependency:tree` what is the actual jaxb used. On a separate note, I'd recommend using Java Time API instead of Joda Time.

Comment: I don't know what you are meaning by "double check the groupId and artifactId" you mean like to make sure I didn't write them badly? If that was the case, shouldn't it not works even in 1.8? For the dependency tree, I did it and the jaxb used are com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.5:compile, javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.5:compile
and com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.5:compile. Considering the date, I agree with you, but even changing it won't change the building result, so I'm more focused about making the application work on java 11.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it was the version of the jaxb plugin which needed to be updated.

The old version, working in java1.8 was 1.6 and I had to update it to 2.5.0.

The new generator is:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.jaxb.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schemagen</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schemagen</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/xsd</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
                    <transformSchemas>
                        <transformSchema>
                            <toFile>model.xsd</toFile>
                        </transformSchema>
                    </transformSchemas>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <packageName>model</packageName>
                    <sources>
                        <source>data/domaine/*.java</source>
                        <source>data/adapter/*.java</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```